# Do I need to submit facebook Login review?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

My FB app is for internal use, not for everybody (i.e not list in app center).

There're several users who use this app to publish contents on their own fb account. So it requires some extra permissions like publish_actions.

Also, I don't want to add them in the Roles section in my app....

In this case, do I need to submit Login Review?

Comment: If you want to ask users that don’t have a role in the app, then yes, of course you need to submit for review.